# how to submit form in Azure Scheduler

Tags: azure, curl, scheduler, azure-scheduler

I have a web-service running at AWS (lets say *example.com*) . I would like to transfer data to the web-service once per hour. I also have Azure account, and I would like to use Azure's Scheduler to transfer data to my web-service.

I can use my web-service by **cUrl** like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type = application/json" -XPOST http://example.com -F imurl=http://example_image.jpg
```

The above **cUrl** statement submits a form by using POST method.
I would like to do the same thing what cUrl does in Azure Scheduler but I could not figure out how to fill the body.

Here is what I did in Scheduler:

[image]

> **Fail Detail is:**
>   Http Action - Response from host '52.164.126.98':
>   'InternalServerError' Response Headers: Connection: close Date: Thu,
>   06 Jul 2017 08:16:17 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)  Body:
>    500
>   Internal Server Error
>
> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The
>   server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your
>   request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the
>   application.

when I check */var/log/apache2/error.log* it says `imurl` is not assigned properly.

Comment: as unclearly stated in the accepted answer, requesting http post form-data is not possible in Azure. But Logic Apps are really cool to go and here [1] is an explanation to learn how to use them.  [1]:http://devslice.net/2016/08/logic-apps-post-request/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using Logic Apps instead of Scheduler for this scenario.

With Logic Apps, start with a recurrence trigger followed by an HTTP action, to send formdata, format the body of the HTTP request like so:

```
"body": {
   "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
   "$multipart": [
      {
         "body": "val0",
         "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"pkey0\""
         }
      },
      {
         "body": "val1",
         "headers": {
            "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"pkey1\""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a Swagger definition of the API you're trying to invoke, simply supply that to the HTTP+Swagger action in Logic Apps and we will populate a composer it for you.